# How to update HTML DOM with immer after State changes?

Tags: javascript, state-management, immer.js

I do not completely understand how to use Immer state management, but I want to update my HTML after state changes with vanilla JS. So in this example, I need to rerender the HTML after baseState object changes. Is this possible with Immer? 
Or should I use it in pair with Observer pattern?

Thanks

```
let baseState = [
    {
        todo: "Learn typescript",
        done: true
    },
    {
        todo: "Try immer",
        done: false
    }
]

baseState = immer.produce(baseState, draftState => {
    draftState.push({todo: "Tweet about its", done: false})
})
```

Comment: Can't you call a `render()` method after modifying the state object? You can't use proxies here because a new object is created each time.

Comment: @D.Pardal like `baseState = immer.produce(baseState, draftState => {
    draftState.push({todo: "Tweet about its", done: false}); 
render(); //????
})`
Or immer has a built method for this?

Comment: Exactly like that.

Comment: @D.Pardal thank you